# Making Jeep Gladiator Sport S (NOT Max Tow) Off-Road Ready

Tags: tires, wheels, jeep, drivetrain, gladiator

So I'm buying a new Jeep Sport S and want to make it off-road ready. I am going to be replacing the tires/wheels and adding a lift. My question is:

- Can a stock Sport S handle 33s... or even 35s? I know they can fit but will I destroy the drivetrain?
- Are there any additional upgrades I should consider on the Sport S to make it off-road worth... upgrade the Axel, Re-Gear it?

The Rubicon alternative is $8000 more and I would rather save a bit. I can get the tires/rims with a hookup pretty cheap so that's not any extra money.

NOTE: This does NOT have the max-tow.

Also would I be better doing the 8k+ for the Rubicon?

---- EDIT 1/13/2024 ----

I want to start with mudding and more tame off-roading, but will quickly end up in West Vigina rock climing and scaling Medium to tough mountains. I'd expect some pretty gnarrly climbs honestly, but I'll never try to do "expert" level. Does that help?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Off-road is a pretty broad term. If you'll edit your question to add detail, it will help produce useful answers. For example, rock climbing, mudding, sand dunes? Or more sedate driving on woodland fire roads, SW desert trails, etc?

Comment: If an off roader with Jeep Gladiator experience isn't around to help, perhaps Jeep forums with off roaders can help.

Comment: @Mta I update the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade: Based on my own experiences when I was young and . . . never mind . . . a powerful winch with a looong cable can be your best friend off-road. It got me out several times when I was up to the floorboards in mud.

It saved my bacon once on a hill climb when I hit a loose patch and turned a bit sideways, in danger of rolling over.

It cleared fallen trees blocking my way. And I rescued a few off-roaders who had no winch of their own.

Comment: I 100% Bought one! Thanks for the tip